# How to programatically select a cell and retrieve the contents in a Tkinter Treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have a Tkinter Treeview and I wish to programatically (i.e. not selected by the user) pick out a cell in the grid and its contents. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this., Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide us what you have tried so far? Please provide us a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: If you know how to create a row with values in the columns, you should be able to figure out how to retrieve the content of a cell from the [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html). Clue: look at the `.item()` method.

Comment: I was able to get it to work in the end using the following code:


`curItem = PS_Tree.focus()
dict = PS_Tree.item(curItem)
PS_Chosen_ID = dict.get("values", "")
PS_Chosen_ID = str(PS_Chosen_ID[0])`

This is no doubt not the way to do it but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a treeview like this:

```
# Import requrired libraries/packages
from tkinter import Tk, W, NO, ttk, TOP, X

# Create intance of tkinter
root = Tk()

# Create the treeview
tree=ttk.Treeview(root)

# Define columns
tree["columns"]=("one","two","three")
tree.column("#0", width=270, minwidth=270, stretch=NO)
tree.column("one", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=NO)
tree.column("two", width=400, minwidth=200)
tree.column("three", width=80, minwidth=50, stretch=NO)

# Define headings
tree.heading("#0",text="Name",anchor=W)
tree.heading("one", text="Date modified",anchor=W)
tree.heading("two", text="Type",anchor=W)
tree.heading("three", text="Size",anchor=W)

# Define some rows
# Level 1
folder1=tree.insert("", 1, "", text="Folder 1", values=("23-Jun-17 11:05","File folder",""))
tree.insert("", 2, "", text="text_file.txt", values=("23-Jun-17 11:25","TXT file","1 KB"))
# Level 2
tree.insert(folder1, "end", "", text="photo1.png", values=("23-Jun-17 11:28","PNG file","2.6 KB"))
tree.insert(folder1, "end", "", text="photo2.png", values=("23-Jun-17 11:29","PNG file","3.2 KB"))
tree.insert(folder1, "end", "", text="photo3.png", values=("23-Jun-17 11:30","PNG file","3.1 KB"))

# Packing
tree.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

You can then retrieve the values (for instance) of the first row `folder1` as follows:

```
tree.item(folder1)
```

Output (`values` and `text` are the keys you are interested in):

```
{'image': '', 'open': 0, 'tags': '', 'text': 'Folder 1', 'values': ['23-Jun-17 11:05', 'File folder', '']}
```

Hence, it is just a matter of correctly saving the ids of each row so that you can use them afterwards to retrive the values of the row.